# Is it safe to pass the same ExecutorService instance to multiple NioServerSocketChannelFactory in Netty

Tags: java, netty

I have a tcp server running at port xxxx and flash policy server(again tcp) at port 843. Is it ok if I pass the same ExecutorService instance while creating the server bootstrap's for both servers? Will it lead to data corruption?

```
ExecutorService boss = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new NamedThreadFactory("TCP-Server-Boss")
ExecutorService worker = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new NamedThreadFactory("TCP-Server-Worker")
serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(boss,worker))
```

Now I want to pass the same `boss` and `worker` to the flash policy servers `serverBootstrap`. Is this a valid usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExecutorService` returned by `newCachedThreadPool()` is not guaranteed to be threadsafe anywhere in the documentation. So it would be the correct action to create two new `ExecutorService`s.

Im quite sure the instances returned are threadsafe regardless of the documentation, but I would still make two new `ExecutorService`s with different names to ease debugging and readability.

Comment: The reason I asked the q was that the flash policy server would have very little traffic and creating dedicated threads for it looked like a waste. Anyway thanks for the a.

Comment: I dont think you would achieve that regardless. I think Netty is only using the `ExecutorService` as a thread factory so even if they share the `Executor`, they would still both occupy a thread each for the duration of the server.

Comment: Not if I pass in a fixed thread pool executor right? Executors.newsinglethreadexecutor

Comment: Assuming im correct it will still attempt to get the same amount of threads. Wether it will succeed is another matter. Using a fixed thread pool is most likely a bad idea. Its better to configure how many threads Netty should use and let the pool be unbounded.